# Scipy sparse matrix multiplication using to much RAM

Tags: python, scipy

I have two csr sparse matrix 136095x136095 : X and A
with dtype Bool

I want to calculate `X @ A @ X`

But I hit this error :

```
Unable to allocate 93.3 GiB for an array with shape (12525785139,) and data type int64
```

it happens at the line (from scipy code not my code)

```
indices = np.empty(nnz, dtype=idx_dtype)
```

How could I get my result ?
I don't have 100 GB RAM and it seems overkill.

Also

`X@A` works and it runs in 2.9 sec on my laptop

`A@X` works and it runs in 2.9 sec

X is 500M non null elements
A is 2k non null elements
X@A is 40M non null elements
They are symmetric

Comment: what's the `nnz` for `X@A`?  The multiplication increases the density of the result.  I'm guessing the error occurs in the part of `@` that allocates memory for the result of `X@A` multiplying with `X`,

Comment: thank I corrected the nnz. I guess its just too big. I will try to reduce X.

Comment: Even if the arguments are bool, the calculation will done in floats (or possibly same size int).  The underlying C code is compiled for a limited number C types.